# can't find "cscope-index-recursively" variable when I do Meta-X, it only finds "cscope-index-files"

Tags: emacs, cscope

Repro:

1. Open emacs
2. M-x `cscope-index-recursively`

   a. it does not find it, only finds `cscope-index-files`

Installed packages:

```
Source: emacs23
Version: 23.3+1-1ubuntu9.2


Source: cscope 
Version: 15.7a-3.5 
Depends: cscope (>= 15.7a-3.5),
emacs23 | emacsen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cscope-index-recursively` is a variable, not a function, so you cannot invoque it with M-x.  To change its value (and see its description), type M-x customize-variable RET cscope-index-recursively